# Grails - log into files via appender

Tags: file, grails, logging, log4j, appender

This post has NOT been accepted by the mailing list yet.
Hi everyone,

Thank you in advance for any help provided. 
I encounter a problem trying to keep track of my logs into a file, and do not understand what is wrong in the syntax I am using. 
Here are my settings for logging into Config.groovy:

```
[SNIP] 
log4j = { 
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console 
    // appender: 

    appenders { 
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n') 

        file name: "scraperServiceLogger", 
             file: "target/scraperService.log" 
    }

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers 
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP 
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts 
               'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping 
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping 
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading 
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins 
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration 
           'org.springframework', 
           'org.hibernate', 
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate' 
           'grails.app.' 

    error scraperServiceLogger: "grails.app.service.ScraperService"

    warn   'org.mortbay.log' 

    debug 'grails.test.*' 
} 
[/SNIP]
```

Here is how I am trying to use it within my ScraperService.groovy:

```
[SNIP] 
 log.error "test" 
[/SNIP]
```

The file I want to write in is created correctly but the logging in only displayed on console. 
Any help greatly appreciated :)

All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the full package to your service

error scraperServiceLogger: "grails.app.service.com.whatever.ScraperService"

Comment: :) I feel stupid but glad nevertheless. 
Thank you very much ! It did the trick

Comment: Actually, I am having the same problem with Quartz Jobs, but this time the package name is added and nothing is printed into the file. 
The level of log is correct. 

Any info on this ?